# htaccess ignoring just one rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my htaccess file i have defined some rules and all of them are working except one.

The html link is

```
<a href="Games-name-of-game">Name of game</a>
```

The Htaccess is

```
RewriteRule ^Games-([^/]*)$ /gameDescription.php?games=$1 [NC]
```

When i click on the above link, it redirects Games-name-of-game to /gameDescription.php?games=name-of-game

All other rules[redirects] are working fine except this one.

My Htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes

<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

RewriteRule ^Games-([^/]*)$ /gameDescription.php?game=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^Home$ /index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Games$ /games.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^News$ /news.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Videos$ /videos.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Contact$ /contact.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^About$ /about.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Privacy$ /privacy.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Ideas$ /gameDesign.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Profile$ /profile.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^Search/Query/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: You need to post all the others, because one is likely interfering.

Comment: please post the complete htaccess

Comment: Especially since you don't have a `[L]` flag here, a match down the line would be executed after this.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - i have been playing around and added the [L] tags, as well as commenting out some rules, but its still reverting the URL to gameDescription.php?game=$1

Comment: Try `href="Games/name_of_game"' and `RewriteRule ^Games/([^A-Za-z0-9_]*)$ /gameDescription.php?games=$1 [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - removed the word game from the rule and everything is working how it should

Here is my updated htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes

<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$

RewriteRule ^Home$ /index.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Games$ /games.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^News$ /news.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Videos$ /videos.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Contact$ /contact.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^About$ /about.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Privacy$ /privacy.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Ideas$ /gameDesign.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^Profile$ /profile.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^Title-([^/]*)$ /desc.php?game=$1 [NC]

RewriteRule ^Search/Query/([^/]*)$ /search.php?query=$1 [NC]
```